# Building HTML5 Apps Platform

Tags: html, cordova, cross-platform, platform

I would like to know what is the best platform out there to create HTML5 based apps for iOS / Android. I am currently using PhoneGap and the performance is just horrible. It is very slow and I just want to be able to do this guys. Can anyone recommend me a good platform? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The low performance has nothing to do with PhoneGap, it's essentially because of the html-based solution. The WebView(or the browser) renders html and runs javascript pretty slow. If you decide to choose the "native + html" kind of solution, and take the benefit of fast development and cross-platform, you have to deal with the terrible performance of the html rendering by the WebView of each kind of device.

Comment: I have seen smooth HTML5 apps. Do you have an idea on what platform they used?

Comment: Smooth or not depends on the html and js code, not the framework. They are all simple native WebViews. And the performance on iOS is much better than on the other systems. I made this app(http://itunes.apple.com/app/id471851341?mt=8) with PhoneGap, and I think it's smooth enough for me at least on the iOS.

Comment: the problem is, im going to develop a magazine app and that app has a lot of image in it. What advice can u give me to make the best out of phonegap? i heard about this PhoneGap xDK. will it help?

Comment: @AJNaidas If there's not too many dazzling effects or animations in your app, and you prefer fast development rather than the best performance, then you should really try the "native+html" way. And PhoneGap is the best solution for that. Otherwise I'd suggest you to take the native way. The xDK is just another IDE for PhoneGap development.

Comment: thank you very much. I now see how things are going to go in my next few steps with Cross-Platform developing.